# Using nnkDotExpr to create an ident in Nim

Tags: macros, nim-lang

I am trying to use nnkDotExpr in a macro and am getting an error. Specifically I am trying to write a macro which will write a procedure that returns a specific field. I have tried three approaches all of which seem to fail and I am not sure why.

This is the code I have.

```
import macros 

type
    Test_Type = object of RootObj
        Name_HIDDEN: string

macro Name_MacroA*(vType: untyped): untyped =
    var tName = nnkDotExpr(ident("self"), ident("Name_HIDDEN"))
    
    quote do:
        proc Name*(self: var `vType`): string =
            return `tName`

macro Name_MacroB*(vType: untyped): untyped =
    var tName = newNimNode(nnkDotExpr)
    tName.add(ident("self"))
    tName.add(ident("Name_HIDDEN"))

    quote do:
        proc Name*(self: var `vType`): string =
            return `tName`

macro Name_MacroC*(vType: untyped): untyped =
    var tName = nnkDotExpr.newTree(ident("self"), ident("Name_HIDDEN"))

    quote do:
        proc Name*(self: var `vType`): string =
            return `tName`

Name_MacroB(Test_Type)

var tTest: Test_Type
tTest.Name_HIDDEN = "Hello"
echo tTest.Name
```

When I use Name_MacroA I am get the error:

```
Error: attempting to call routine: 'nnkDotExpr'
  found 'nnkDotExpr' [enumField declared in /usr/local/Cellar/nim/2.0.0_1/nim/lib/core/macros.nim(45, 5)]
```

Name_MacroA is an attempt to match the code from the nnkDotExpr reference in
[Nim Macros](https://nim-lang.org/1.2.0/macros.html).

When I use Name_MacroB or Name_MacroC I get the error:

```
template/generic instantiation of `Name_MacroB` from here test4.nim(17, 20) Error: undeclared identifier: 'self'
candidates (edit distance, scope distance); see '--spellSuggest': 
 (2, 4): 'del'
 (2, 4): 'ref'
 (2, 4): 'send'
```

Name_MacroB is an attempt to match the code from [Nim Macros](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/8427)

Name_MacroC is an attempt to match code from [Nim Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019297/how-do-i-access-an-object-field-via-its-field-name-in-string-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you are trying to call `nnkDotExpr` when its an enum. For [NimNodeKind](https://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#NimNodeKind)'s like `nnkDotExpr` you need to use [newTree](https://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#newTree%2CNimNodeKind%2Cvarargs%5BNimNode%5D).

The second issue is that `quote do` is generating a unique symbol for the `self` parameter so you need to make it use your own ident like so

```
    # Create your own ident
    let selfIdent = ident"self"
    # Can use genSym if you think there might be conflicts
    # let selfIdent = genSym(nskParam, "self")
    tName.add(selfIdent) 
    tName.add(ident("Name_HIDDEN"))

    quote do:
        # Now it uses your symbol here instead of making a new one
        proc Name*(`selfIdent`: var `vType`): string =
            return `tName`
```

Also there is [newDotExpr](https://nim-lang.org/docs/macros.html#newDotExpr%2CNimNode%2CNimNode) which makes creating dot expressions simplier